# Sort by subset fields in MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, driver

I am trying to sort my collection by subset fields but 10gen C# driver throws exception and says that there is no such a field. Field is exist but i think problem is that MongoDB does not sort by subset field's field like below

```
collection.FindAll().SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("Comments.Score")).SetLimit(10);
```

It is actualy above query is not logical because i can not order Posts by Comments.Score . What i want to achieve is that I want to sort Posts by max Comment.Score value.

Document model is like below:

```
{
    Comments:[{Score:20,CommentBody:"blabla"},{...}]
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample document in your collection?

Comment: `Comments.Score` refers to the subproperty `Score` of the property `Comments`.     What you have in your document is really an array. The Score property does not exist in the document itself.

Are you intending to store comments as a property of a single document (like in your example)? or as actually independent comments in a collection?

Comment: I am not using Comments as a single property on Post. It is an array of Comment objects. "Comments.Score" can make you feel Comments is a property it is because of dotted notation of MongoDb.